# Type of clause in these examples/usage

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

The character was intentionally designed to be very charismatic and articulate, ***his main source of fear being derived from his warped sense of reasoning.***

His features contort with obvious pain as he tells his story, ***his memories of Caroline clearly something he holds precious.***

What are the bolded parts of the sentence called, and how do they differ from complete sentences in general and in these examples ?

Comment: Both those sentences are complete.

Comment: @ Lambie I of course agree that the sentences are complete, but the question appears to be about the passages in bold. Those passages are neither complete sentences nor even clauses.

Comment: What's missing from both bolded sections in terms of them not being clauses. Other than a subordinate conjunction.

Comment: No verb associated with the main verb.

Answer (score 1):

It is an example of a **nominative absolute construction** - it is a construction that has a сlose semantic connection with the rest of a sentence, although gramatically not connected with this rest of the sentence with any means. It is always separated by a comma from the rest of a sentence.

This construction always has a subject, after which there is always a participle or an infinitive.

For example, in your sentence:

> The character was intentionally designed to be very charismatic and articulate, **his main source of fear being derived from his warped sense of reasoning**.

The subject of a nominative absolute construction (in bold) is "his main source of fear" and participle is "being derived".

Sometimes, when a participle in a nominative absolute construction is "being" after which subject complement takes place, the "being" can be omitted. For example, your sentence

> His features contort with obvious pain as he tells his story, **his memories of Caroline clearly something he holds precious**.

is a shorthand for

> His features contort with obvious pain as he tells his story, **his memories of Caroline *being* clearly something he holds precious**.

Answer (score 0):

The passages in bold type in your examples are not complete clauses.

There is nothing grammatically wrong with either sentence; native speakers say things like that all the time. Good writers, however, do not write like that because the sentences are unclear.

In your first example, what does being charismatic and articulate have to do with being fearful or having warped logic? Something is missing. Perhaps something like: "Nevertheless, his warped perception made him fearful." Now that suggestion may not reflect what you wanted to say at all, but just tacking on "his main source of fear being derived" does not relate to the first part of the sentence. You may know how the two parts relate, but your reader will not.

The second sentence is considerably clearer, but can be made to express exactly what I am reasonably sure you want to convey. There is a causal relationship that is not made explicit.

"His memories of Caroline are clearly something he holds precious because his features contort with pain as he tells his story."